# Unit testing curried functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, functional-programming

I am trying to figure out what the correct way of thinking about this is. I am trying to play around with some functional programming paradigm in python. I know it is not a functional language, but the concepts can translate.

Lets say I have a set of functions like:

```
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
  return x + y

add_one = partial(add, y=1)
add_two = partial(add, y=2)
add_three = partial(add, y=3)

fut = lambda x: add_three(add_one(add_two(x)))
```

The question is, do I unit test the function under test (`fut`)? And would I unit test `add_one`, `add_two` and `add_three`?

It is an implementation detail in my mind that `add_one` is a partial of `add`, but it feels weird to unit test if I have "complete" coverage of `add`.

Lets extend this for a minute and extend it towards a more realistic system.

```
class Save(Protocol):
  def __call__(self, x: int): ...

def save_to_disk(x: int, file_name:str) -> None:
  """
  Implementation of saving something to a disk
  """
  ...

save: Save = partial(save_to_disk, file_name="random_file")

def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
  return x + y

add_one = partial(add, y=1)

fut: Save = lambda x: save(add_one(x))
```

I now have a function that handles IO and some work generating the data to save. Do I unit test `fut` here? Do I assume that the currying is just implementation details and leave it for integration tests?

I feel a little lost on this one because in a OO world, I know how I could unit test some of this chaining with mocks but it seems backwards and against some of the functional paradigm and what I am actively trying to avoid by playing around with it.

My gut feeling right now is that the curried functions are integration testing and as long as everything is tested individually showing the components work than the chain I can leave for integration testing I can prove that the system as a whole works.

Comment: You don't need to unit test partially applied curried functions separatly. But as soon as you compose such functions (whether partially applied or not) i'd consider the result another unit and would test it as such.

Comment: where do you draw the line I guess would be my follow question. If the sub functions have complicated logic it seems like a lot copy unit tests around. Rather than composing the functions the way I did I also could have nested the functions. I have been playing around with accepting `Save` as a function argument with the implementation set as default so I could stub it out at test time. Is this how you approach chains of functions?

Comment: I actually wouldn't draw a line: If you unit tested a curried function you don't need to test the partially applied variants of this very function. But if you compose functions - and with composition i mean combining two functions in a way that another function is yielded, then you need to test this resulting function too. A higher order function that takes a function argument must thus be unit tested with any function that might be passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first example:

```
add_one = partial(add, y=1)
add_two = partial(add, y=2)
add_three = partial(add, y=3)

fut = lambda x: add_three(add_one(add_two(x)))
```

Assuming that `add_one`, `add_two` and `add_three` are only used locally for the computation of `fut`, I see no need to test these functions: They are essentially just calls to `add`, which you already tested.  Without currying, the code would just contain three calls to add with some constant arguments.

And, since this is all still quite trivial, there is no much value in setting up individual tests for these curried functions.  Things might be different if you would be setting up some more complex intermediate function, let's call it `bigger_helper`.  Such a function might be worth to test individually, to reduce the overall testing effort in a divide-and-conquer way.  (Note that this relates to testing private methods, which some people strongly object to.  I am not that strict and think that there are cases where testing private methods can be the better overall tradeoff between testing goals.)

With respect to your second scenario I agree that it has to be handled in integration testing, but I am not sure I understood your reasoning correctly.  For me, this is not a candidate for unit-testing for the following reason: The function does not contain any computations, but only interactions.  Thus, when you think about which bugs you could find in the isolated code (that is, when mocking the actual writing to disk), it seems to me that there aren't any.  Bugs will rather be like, are you calling the IO operations in the proper order with the right arguments, and does this all fit to the file system's structure etc: All these questions you cannot answer in the isolated code with mocks, since you will implement your mocks according to your (possibly wrong) assumptions.  Consequently, you can skip unit-testing here and should directly go to integration testing in that scenario.

And, this reasoning for integration-testing is not related in any way to the currying, but just to the lack of computations.

Answer (score 0):

If `add` has been tested then I don't think each partial application needs it's own unit test. However, I would unit test `fut` by mocking or spying on `add_one`, `add_two`, and `add_three` (this shouldn't be difficult with a decent testing framework) and making sure that they are called with the correct arguments.

So, my unit test would expect that `add_two` is called with whatever `fut` is called with, `add_one` is called with whatever `add_two` returns, and `add_three` is called with whatever `add_two` returns.